# How to random numbers in the range -0.8 to 0.8 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Could you guys show me how to generate random numbers in range of -0.8 to 0.8.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Mozilla Developer Network(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
var randomNumber = getRandomArbitrary(-0.8,0.8));
```